# An App ID with identifier is not available | xCode 7.3 | Failed to locate matching signing assets

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode7.3

I successfully register an app ID at http://developer.apple.com (say com.laserlike.laserlike). I also successfully created the distribution profile. When I `archive` the appplication in `xCode 7.3`, it succeeds. But when I click on `upload to app store`, then it following error occurs:-

> An App ID with identifier is not available

Note:-

- I am using the xCode 7.3

[image]

Comment: did you do all required actions on itunesconnect.apple.com?

Comment: yes, I created app ID with appropriate bundle identifier, create distribution profile(selected right app ID). I keep the same identifier in Xcode project.

Comment: it's not the end. you must create an application on https://itunesconnect.apple.com to be able to upload binary to AppStore

Comment: Yep, I also take care of all the necessary steps at itunesconnect.apple.com. I updated my Xcode yesterday(7.3). I think it is because of latest Xcode glitch.

Comment: is your application in iTunesConnect in state of 'awaiting for binary upload'?

Comment: yes. I tried with Xcode 7.1, it uploads successfully. Thanks for your time @heximal

Comment: I think it's broken recently with Xcode 7.3, it used to work before. Before Xcode would automatically generate provisioning profiles with "XC: " or "XC Ad Hoc: " prefixes, but now you need to create them by hand, which kind of defeats the purpose of automatic provisioning profile management, so I'm almost sure it's not indented.

Comment: I had this problem creating an Ad Hoc build for an existing app after I upgraded to Xcode 7.3 (although, oddly, not immediately). Eventually I got it working after I deleted the "XC: " provisioning profiles and created a new Ad Hoc profile manually.